# Node.js program skipping 1st user input function and only executing 2nd one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-input, stdin, readline

In my node.js program, I have 2 user input functions. Before I added the 2nd one, it was working perfectly fine. After adding the 2nd one, the program directly goes to the 2nd one and executes that and completely skips the area of the code with the 1st user input function. I'm not sure why this could be? Is there a way I could have the entire program execute from top to bottom? Here's the gist of the code I'm working on:

```js
var user_answer; 
var user_answer2;
const readline = require("readline"); // For user-input
const user_input = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout 
});

const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const url = //insert url 
const headers = {
  //insert headers
}
const body = {
    //insert body info
}

fetch(url, { method: 'POST', headers: headers, body: body})
  .then((res) => {
     return res.json()
})

.then((json) => {
  user_input.question("Asking question here: ", function(user_answer) { //1ST USER INPUT FUNCTION 
  for(/* insert for-loop conditions here */) {
    //insert code to print stuff out during for-loop

  }
    user_input.close();
});
});
user_input.question("How are you? ", function(user_answer2) { //2ND USER INPUT FUNCTION 
    if (user_answer2 == 0) {
      console.log('hi');
      user_input.close();
    }
});

user_input.on("close", function() {
  process.exit(0);

});
```